# Should the compiler instantiate all parameter dependent types even if the parameter count of the overloaded function does not match

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider a simple example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, std::size_t N>
struct MaybeAssert {
    using type = T;
    static_assert(N < 1, "Assertion");
};

template <class T>
void foo(typename MaybeAssert<T, 0>::type) {
}

template <class T>
void foo(typename MaybeAssert<T, 0>::type, 
         typename MaybeAssert<T, 1>::type) {
}

int main() {
   foo<int>(2);
}
```

[[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ihmJnpVESMBbD8wm) instantiate `MaybeAssert<T, 1>` which in the example triggers `static_assert`.

[[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IeZ4MqvFcuamPXIs) on the other hand instantiate the types only if the number of function template parameters match. Which compiler is right?

Comment: FWIW MSVS 2017 behaves as clang does.

Comment: On the other hand I think icc acts like gcc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are valid [[temp.inst]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#7) :

> If the overload resolution process can determine the correct function to call without instantiating a class template definition, it is unspecified whether that instantiation actually takes place.

Comment: didn't know that compiler can choose there! Thanks!